# Problema compilando Flutter para desktop en linux

Tags: c++, linux, flutter, ubuntu

Estoy tratando de compilar un proyecto de Flutter para Desktop en Linux. Es el proyecto por default. Estoy usando IntelliJ ide ultimate, y la version de linux es Ubuntu 22.04 lts. Este es el output que me da:

```
Connected devices:
Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 5.19.0-45-generic
Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.133
[1]: Linux (linux)
[2]: Chrome (chrome)
Please choose one (or "q" to quit): 1
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

  "/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /media/victor/E808BD0F08BCDE2E/Programacion/--03PROYECTOS--/repin2/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_bad93 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_bad93.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_bad93
    FAILED: cmTC_bad93 
    : && /usr/bin/clang++   CMakeFiles/cmTC_bad93.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_bad93   && :
    /usr/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lstdc++: No existe el archivo o el directorio
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

Alguien sabe como podria arreglar el problema?

Comment: Sugieras que corras el comando `flutter doctor` para ver si cuentas con todas las herramientas necesarias. O `flutter doctor -v` que da más información.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problema resuelto, aqui esta lo que hice:

### 1-Aplicar este comando en la consola de linux:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so`

#### Explicacion:

- Se utiliza para crear un enlace simbólico entre dos archivos. En este caso, se está creando un enlace simbólico entre /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 y /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.
- Un enlace simbólico es un tipo especial de archivo que apunta a otro archivo o directorio. En este caso, el enlace simbólico se está creando para que el archivo /usr/lib/libstdc++.so apunte al archivo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6. Esto es útil en situaciones en las que un programa o biblioteca requiere un archivo en una ubicación específica, pero el archivo se encuentra en otra ubicación.

### 2-Luego de esto recibi este output:

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
Building Linux application...                                           
Exception: Build process failed
```

#### Explicacion:

- El output que se muestra indica que se está produciendo un error al compilar el proyecto de Flutter en Linux. El mensaje de error específico es "fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found", lo que indica que el archivo 'type_traits' no se encuentra en el sistema.
- Este error puede ser causado por varias razones, como problemas con las dependencias, problemas con el sistema operativo o problemas con el código.

##### Este lo resolvi instalando `libstdc++-12-dev` con el siguiente comando:

`sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev`

#### Explicaicion:

- El comando `sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev` resolvió el problema porque instaló la biblioteca `libstdc++-12-dev` en el sistema. El error "fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found" indica que el archivo type_traits no se encontraba en el sistema y era necesario para la compilación del proyecto.
- La biblioteca libstdc++-12-dev proporciona implementaciones de plantillas y funciones para la biblioteca estándar de C++ en el sistema. Al instalar esta biblioteca, se agregan los archivos necesarios, como type_traits, que se requieren durante la compilación.
- Al ejecutar el comando `sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev`, se descarga e instala la biblioteca `libstdc++-12-dev` en el sistema, lo que permite que el compilador encuentre el archivo type_traits y resuelva el error de compilación.

### 3- Luego de esto solo se debe reconstruir el proyecto y... Problema resuelto!!!

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Por favor, añade más descripción a tu respuesta. Si bien el código o la solución que plantes puede ser efectiva para resolver el problema, es crucial entenderlo realmente. Puede ser que tú lo entiendas, pero puede haber gente con el mismo problema que a lo mejor no entienda totalmente la solución. Copiar y pegar código no es una solución. Puedes leer: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección. Ahora creo que ya quedo como debe ser.